# Filtering with multiple criteria on tidy data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm struggling with the filter (dplyr) function on a tidy dataframe:

```
data1<-data.frame("Time"=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                  "Variable"=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),6),
                  "Value"=c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,3,10,1,3,7,2,1,4,2,3,1,5,13))
```

What I want to do is to filter the time when variable "a" is equal to 2 and when variable "a" is as it max.
For first case mi code is:

```
data1<-data1%>%
  group_by(Time)%>%
  filter(any(Variable=="a" & Value==2))
```

and works fine and gives me:

```
Time Variable Value
2    a        2 
2    b        1
2    c        4
2    d        2
```

Don't now how could be for a=max(a), I tried with:

```
data1<-data1%>%
  group_by(Time)%>%
  filter(any(Variable=="a" & Value==max(Value)))
```

but doesn't work (becaus max is calculated on all column Variable) I think I need something like 
Value=max(Value)[Variable$a].
The filtered must act this way:

```
Time Variable Value
3    a        10 
3    b        1
3    c        3
3    d        7
```

I prefer a solution with dplyr. Can anyone give me a general rule for filtering on tidy df with multiple criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)
data1%>%
  filter(Time == Time[Value == max(Value[Variable == "a"])])
```

And a data.table way

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
data1[Time == Time[Value == max(Value[Variable == "a"])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

additional option

```
data1 %>% 
  filter(Variable == "a") %>% 
  filter(Value == max(Value, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  select(Time) %>% 
  left_join(., data1, by = "Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edited criteria this should provide the desired results.

```
data1 <- data1 %>%
         group_by(Time) %>%
         filter(any(Variable=="a" & 
                    Value==max(data1$Value[data1$Variable == 'a'])))
```

Comment: thank you for the support. I need to have all the variables in the filtered df, not only "a". I re-edit my question becuse, I know, is not so clear.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but is there a way to do it in a "dplyr-tidy" way, without base r command and without subsetting again the original df in the filter function?